# how to set a combobox selected value using knockout.js?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

```
         $.getJSON(
                    'Home/GetAllEmployees',
                    function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                            viewModel.EmployeeList.push(new EmployeeObj(val));
                        });
                    }
           );
```

This code loads my EmployeeList inside a comboBox without any problem.  I have another table which have employee records.  Each record has an employee id assigned to it. When running my application it iterates the employee record table and if it has employee id it will send that employee id to the comboBox and the comboBox will display the name of the specified employee.
**MY PROBLEM:**
Since I am new to Knockout.js I am having problem with this comboBox.  I don't know how to display an employee name based on a provided employee id.

Here is how I load the employee list into the ComboBox:

```
    <select data-bind="options: EmployeeList, optionsText: 'SELECTED_NAME', 
    optionsValue: 'SELECTED_ID', value: SELECTED_ID, selectedIndex: SELECTED_ID, 
    optionsCaption: 'Select Employee....' ">
    </select>
```

This works fine.  I am able to see all employees en the comboBox...

Comment: I see code that creates an `EmployeeList`, but I don't see any comboBox code. Can you post it?

Comment: How about something like Example 4 from the documentation on the ["options" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html)

Comment: Did you find a answer ? If not I think you should fiddle with the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<select id="selectEmployee" data-bind="options: EmployeeList,
    optionsText: function (item) {
        return item.empName;
    },
    optionsValue: function (item) {
        return item.empId;
    },
    value: $root.selectedEmpId">
</select>
```